# Help with Stash Conditionals

Tags: stash, count

Hoping someone can help me with this problem. I have a list of channel entries that I am storing in a stash tag then outputting the complete list, but if there are no entries then it displays something else.

What I am hoping to do is if the total count of entries == 0 then display one thing, if the count == 1 then display something else and finally if the count is > 1 then display a third option to the viewer.

Here is the code that I currently have.

```
{exp:stash:set name="dynamic_adventure" trim="yes" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="adventure_settings" dynamic="no" author_id="CURRENT_USER"}    

          {exp:switchee variable="{embed:adventure_name}" parse="inward"}

              {case value="{dynamic_adventure_template:title}"}

                    <a href="{path="admin/{dynamic_adventure_template:url_title}"}/{url_title}" class="button small red">View Adventure</a><br>

              {/case}
              {case value=""}

              {/case}
          {/exp:switchee}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="dynamic_adventure"} }
        <h2 class="th-adventure-title">{embed:adventure_name}</h2>
        {exp:stash:get name="dynamic_adventure"}
{if:else}
    <h2 class="th-adventure-title">{embed:adventure_name}</h2>
    <a href="{path="admin/new-adventure"}" class="button small red">Start New Adventure</a>
{/if}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the total_results of `channel:entries` on a stash variable.

```
{exp:stash:set name="dynamic_adventure" trim="yes" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="adventure_settings" dynamic="no" author_id="CURRENT_USER"}    

          {exp:switchee variable="{embed:adventure_name}" parse="inward"}

              {case value="{dynamic_adventure_template:title}"}

                    <a href="{path="admin/{dynamic_adventure_template:url_title}"}/{url_title}" class="button small red">View Adventure</a><br>
                    {if count == 1}
                        {exp:stash:set name="dynamic_adventure_total"}{total_results}{/exp:stash:set}
                    {/if}
              {/case}
              {case value=""}

              {/case}
          {/exp:switchee}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Then, you can use the variable for conditionals.

```
{if "{exp:stash:get name='dynamic_adventure_total'}" == "1"}
    [...]
{if:elseif {exp:stash:not_empty name="dynamic_adventure"} }
        <h2 class="th-adventure-title">{embed:adventure_name}</h2>
        {exp:stash:get name="dynamic_adventure"}
{if:else}
    <h2 class="th-adventure-title">{embed:adventure_name}</h2>
    <a href="{path="admin/new-adventure"}" class="button small red">Start New Adventure</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there something else I need to include when I set the stash? I keep getting a list_count of 1 even though it is more.

Comment: Please, forgive me. I thought you was using a stash list, but you're using a simple stash variable. I gonna update my answer.